# How to get names of cells in matrix (e.g., correlation matrix) which match a condition in R using row and column names for cell names?

Tags: r

I often need deal with large correlation matrices between sets of variables, and I want to know which correlations meet a given condition (e.g., are above .2 or .3 or absolute .2 or .3) and so on. So given a correlation matrix, it would be useful if I could get the pairs of variables that form correlations that satisfy a condition.

To make it a little more concrete, here is  matrix

```
x <- matrix(1:9, nrow = 3)
rownames(x) <- colnames(x) <- c("a", "b", "c")
x

# x
#   a b c
# a 1 4 7
# b 2 5 8
# c 3 6 9
```

I want a function that allows me to specify a cell condition, and then will return names for matching cells.

- e.g., > 8 returns "c:c"
- odd number returns "a:a", "c:a", ... "c:c"

Comment: Not a direct answer but an alternative. What about getting a reduced table of row and col locations via `which(x >= 8, arr.ind = TRUE)`.

Answer (score 1):

The following function takes a matrix and a function. The function should return TRUE/FALSE for each cell value.

Using the sample matrix:

```
x <- matrix(1:9, nrow = 3)
rownames(x) <- colnames(x) <- c("a", "b", "c")
```

The function is:

```
cell_matches <- function(x, FUN =  function(X) X > .2) {
    cellnames <- outer(row.names(x), colnames(x), function(X, Y) paste0(X, ":", Y))
    cellnames[FUN(x) ]
}
```

Thus, using the matrix above following works:

```
cell_matches(x, function(X) X > 8)
# [1] "c:c"
cell_matches(x, function(X) X %% 2 == 1)
# [1] "a:a" "c:a" "b:b" "a:c" "c:c"
```

Application to correlation matrix:

```
# correlations above .80
cell_matches(cor(mtcars), function(X) X > .80 & X != 1)    
# [1] "disp:cyl" "hp:cyl"   "cyl:disp" "wt:disp"  "cyl:hp"   "disp:wt"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
check_cor <- function(mat,FUN)
{
  apply(which(FUN(x), arr.ind = TRUE),1,
    function(i)
     {
      paste0(row.names(mat)[i[1]],':',colnames(mat)[i[2]])
     }
  )
}

check_cor(cor(mtcars), function(X) X > .80 & X != 1)
```

Comment: This looks like a much more natural answer. Rather than building all possible combinations, it builds only the ones that satisfy the logical test. I would have chosen to use `which( FUN(x) , arr.ind=TRUE)` and then use the first column to choose the rownames to paste and use the second column to choose the colnames, but it's tow ways to use the arr.ind option in which.